# should I use the most recent android studio version?

Tags: android

just want to know what if I am not using the most recent version of android studio , will I be  able to continue ? I am still using beta version and I am getting errors , is that just because i do not use the most recent version? I am getting errors like

```
     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
     > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: The most recent version of Android Studio isn't a beta anymore...hence it is more stable. So I recommend updating to the latest version and downloading the most recent build tools etc

Answer (score 0):

Latest Android Studio is not beta. You better Download the newest version and update the SDK and get back to work.

[download Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: I know guys about the latest version ,my question is about how important is it to work with the latest version , i am seeking deep understanding

Comment: yes i am an android developer. I have much experience in developing android applications. And I have face so many issues with lower versions of adt bundles , sdk s , and also with android studio also. It is so important that you are up to date. When a issue is about a lower version it is so hard to detect the problem also because we are only focusing about code errors. It barley come to our mind that this could be a version problem. These are the thing what we practically face.